# Setting action listener on system applications

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, system, action

How can I set the `action listener` on system applications?

What I want is: when I start writing on the notepad, my action listener should detect it and I should be able to view what I had typed. The same that happens in a `keylogger`.

This was just the case of notepad but I want that every time I type something my program should be able to view it.

Example: after opening Chrome, I typed `java` in the search bar. Now my program's action listener should be able to detect what I typed.

Comment: You can't use core Java without additional native code to write key loggers.  You'll need to find some other tool for your nefarious plans. Note that this has nothing to do with Swing or GUI coding and all to do with OS hooks (or kernal access).

Comment: Definitely not a Java Swing question. You'll probably have to write a hook (in C) for that and then use some IPC mechanism (e.g. localhost socket) to communicate to your Java program.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels @ jfpoilpret thank you ! I was not aware of it.

Comment: However you want to do it, Stack Overflow is not a place to ask about implementing keyloggers.

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen that was just a question.I didn't ask specifically how to implement `key loggers` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in Java alone. Period. You may try JNI, but definitely not in Java alone.

Comment: Thank you ! I was not aware of it.