# Event handling in keylogger

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, keylogger

While thinking of making a keylogger here I learnt how to register `listener class` with `JFrame` problem with this approach is that it works when `JFrame` is in focus otherwise it does not. My question is there any other object with which I can register my listener class and can get the key pressed whether `JFrame` was in focus or not.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KeyListenerTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    KeyListenerTest()
    {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        System.out.println( ke.getKeyChar() );
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         KeyListenerTest app = new  KeyListenerTest();
         app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
         app.setSize(500, 500);
         //app.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting action listener on system applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172556/setting-action-listener-on-system-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is the wrong language for the job. you can't perform or catch events outside of the vm your application is running in.